# pycryptodome package running on python 3.8 for encrypting and decrypting AES 128 in ECB mode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying my hands on encryption and decryption though I have very little knowledge of it.

I stumbled upon a document [Doc](https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/04/09/python-pycrypto-using-aes-128-in-ecb-mode/) but mostly it is on python2.7
and also the library has also been changed.

I am running python 3.8 on my machine. the library I am using is "pycryptodome".

And I am trying to run this below code which is for the library "pycrypto".

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
 
key = 'assignmentToSetu'
 
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
msg =cipher.encrypt('TechTutorialsX!!TechTutorialsX!!')
print (type(msg))
 
print(msg.encode("hex"))
 
decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
print(decipher.decrypt(msg))
```

I am getting an error which I feel is with the library I am using.

error:

```
 cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
  File "D:\work\scrap\billFetch\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 232, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\work\scrap\billFetch\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
  File "D:\work\scrap\billFetch\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py", line 216, in _create_ecb_cipher   
    cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
  File "D:\work\scrap\billFetch\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 103, in _create_base_cipher        
    result = start_operation(c_uint8_ptr(key),
  File "D:\work\scrap\billFetch\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py", line 232, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Under Python 3.8: For key and plaintext bytes literals must be applied (i.e. use `b'assignmentToSetu'` instead of `'assignmentToSetu'` or encode e.g. with `'assignmentToSetu'.encode('utf8')`). Instead of `msg.encode('hex')` apply `msg.hex()`.

Comment: Also note that the ECB mode is insecure. Use a mode with an IV, preferably authenticated encryption, e.g. GCM.

Comment: @Topaco. 
I tried to upload the file on lambda. I am getting an error suggesting the library is not compatible with lambda OS